# OneDrive account on Mac stopped working; trying to re-add account makes preferences dialog exit

Tags: macos, onedrive, microsoft

I've used two Windows accounts (one personal, one business) with OneDrive on a Mac for many years.  Recently, I noticed the icon associated with the business account was no longer in the system menu.

I've done the typical things... reinstall the app, remove any keychain entries, run the "reset" app within the OneDrive app package, and nothing works.

If I open preferences, I only see my personal account.  If I attempt to add the business account, the preferences dialog just exits!

Any ideas?

Comment: It appears Microsoft is aware of the issue https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/big-sur-11-6-onedrive.2310591/page-3

Comment: The issue has been resolved by Microsoft: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/2nd-onedrive-account-in-m1-macbook-pro/1ee73a0c-71c9-44cf-be3b-b7dc19aef863?page=3&auth=1

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has resolved the issue.  [Here is the official notice](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/2nd-onedrive-account-in-m1-macbook-pro/1ee73a0c-71c9-44cf-be3b-b7dc19aef863?page=3&auth=1).